# Calculate Radians In Order To Have Player Face Unit - From Player(X,Y) to Unit(X,Y)

Tags: trigonometry

Given a Player.X and Player.Y, and a Unit.X and Unit.Y, what is the formula to calculate the proper amount in radians (or degrees) to apply to the player, so that the player is facing directly towards the units x,y position?

Minimum radians is $0$, maximum radians is $2\pi$ ($360$ degrees) for radians in the game I am modding in C++.

Example:

Player.x = $-9000$, Player.y = $-150$

Unit.x = $-8950$, Unit.y =$ -132$

I am not great at math, so thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the player's perspective, he needs to look in the direction (Unit.X-Player.X, Unit.Y-Player.Y). If you know the two components, in most programming languages you would use 'arctan2' or 'atan2' function. You can look it up on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).
So your final angle (in radians) is given by atan2(Unit.Y-Player.Y, Unit.X-Player.X)

Comment: Thanks, that works great!

Any ideas on implementation of math/logic for checking whether to press LEFT or RIGHT arrow on the keyboard - based on current facing degrees of the player vs degrees the player needs to face?

For example I don't want to turn 350 degrees to the right when I could just turn 10 degrees to the left.

Comment: Check the language in which you are implementing the algorithm, see what atan2 returns. If the answer is from $-pi$ to $pi$, positive angles are to the left (counterclockwise) and negative angles are to the right (clockwise). If atan2 returns from 0 to $2\pi$, see if the answer is greater than $\pi$. If it is, turn right (clockwise) $2\pi$ minus the answer from atan2.